# Drag and drop exception. Desktop objects

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, drag-and-drop

I am using Drag & Drop ListView on files (directories or any kind of files). 
When i drag&drop My Computer or Bin from Desktop NullReferenceException happens.

All i want is to skip this element (display some text in log textbox or smthing).
I have no idea how to achieve that. I don't know what kind of object is MyComputer element from Desktop.

Here's my code after cutting useless to this subject logic:

```
private void Directories_ListView_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {

        string[] DroppedDirectories = (string[]) e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop,false); //array of dd files paths
        try
        {
            foreach (var directory in DroppedDirectories) // here Exception  occurs this loop process all dragged and drop files 
            {
                ListViewItem Dir = new ListViewItem(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(directory));
                //Place for some checking Logic
                if (GetDir.IsDirectory(directory))
                {
                   (.....);// Doing some things
                }
                else
                    LogList.Items.Add(DateTime.Now + ": Entry " + Dir.Text + " is not a directory");

            }
        }
        catch(Exception) // it only stops app from crashing, 
        {
            LogList.Items.Add(DateTime.Now + "One of elements was Mycomputer or Bin, process stopped ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: WinForms? WPF? UWP? Something else? The "desktop" tag is pretty vague.

Comment: Corrected that. Your link is not related to the subject anyway.

Comment: How is your listview configured? I'm trying to implement your code but I'm finding that event with AllowDrop = true and handling DragDrop. When I drag the Recycle bin from my desktop it shows the not allowed symbol and won't drop it.

Comment: @HandbagCrab You need the DragEnter event.

Comment: @TamaraL96 You said you are getting a NullReferenceException. The linked question contains a comprehensive walkthrough on how to debug those kinds of exceptions, hence the duplicate.

Comment: @TamaraL96 For example, the line throwing the exception is `foreach (var directory in DroppedDirectories)`. The only variable getting referenced in that line is `DroppedDirectories`, so that must be `null`, which means the line _assigning_ that variable must be returning `null`. So now we've arrived at the _real_ issue, which is that `e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop,false)` is returning `null`.

Comment: @TamaraL96 Consulting the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5x40k0y6(v=vs.110).aspx) for that function, it says it returns `null` if there is no data in the event that can be converted to the specified format (in this case, `DataFormats.FileDrop`). Now we have the _real real_ issue that the drag-drop event doesn't contain the data you are expecting to be getting. (This can be checked beforehand by using the `GetDataPresent` method instead of relying on a `null` value or thrown exception.)

Comment: @TamaraL96 This is why posting a question about a NullReferenceException is generally not going to get the kind or quality of answers you are hoping for. NREs are just symptoms of what the _real_ problem is. If you get an NRE, follow the steps in the linked question. When you discover what the actual problem is, post a question about _that_ (assuming following the steps doesn't lead you to the solution on its own).

Comment: @HandbagCrab In Listview i enabled dragEnter and DragDrop events. DragEnter method contains only:
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;

Comment: @LarsTech, Ah yes. If I move the above code into DragEnter I get the error as soon as I drag over. It is the string[] DroppedEntries that is failing as I've put debug.WriteLine(DroppedEntries == null ? "Yes" : "No") and it's printing Yes. So the assumption of what is in e.GetData() needs to be verified before you attempt to assign it to DroppedEntries as Abion47 says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to LarsTech and Abion47 your solution is to wrap your drag drop code in this condition:

```
if (e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false) != null)
{
    string[] DroppedDirectories = (string[]) e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop,false);

    foreach(string directory in DroppedDirectories)
    {
        try
        {
            ListViewItem Dir = new ListViewItem(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(directory));
            //Rest of code
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            LogList.Items.Add(DateTime.Now + ": Entry " + directory + " is not a directory");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help to everyone :) @Abion47 Thank you for performing solution process.

Comment: Code works fine, but if you drag and drop few files and one of them is Bin or Mycomputer, the other ones are still not processed. I will try to figure it out tommorow.

Comment: You'll need to check each "directory" before you process it - or just wrap the contents of the foreach loop in a try catch, that way you only catch the item that fails and can then process the next. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I'll will test your improved code  :) My conception is to get rid of foreach loop and replacing it by for loop (i<Array.length). Then i can test whether the value in array is null.